# Problem Migrating a ntive query from Hibernate to EclipseLink 2.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I'll appreciate if anyone can point me to a solution as to why I could be getting the error below in an attempt to execute the following query which caused no problem whatsoever with Hibernate:

The Entity (Step.java):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IAS_STEP")
public class Step implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date tarih;

    private long formId;

    private Byte faz;

    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

The method in the controller class:

```
public byte getMaxPhase(String sid, long form_id) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        Query q = em
                .createQuery(
                        "select max(faz) as mf from Step s where s.id = :sid and s.formId = :formId")
                .setParameter("sid", sid)
                .setParameter("formId", form_id);
        return ((Byte) q.getSingleResult()).byteValue();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

This worked just fine in Hibernate, but causes an error in EclipseLink 2.0.

Anyone can suggest a workaround?

Comment: Where is the native query, and what is the error? You are using `em.createQuery(...)` and not `em.createNativeQuery(...)`.

Comment: It worked just fine without a native query and object prefix on Hibernate, but for the sake of best practices, I converted it to a native query. `BigDecimal bd; Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select max(faz) as mf from IAS_STEP aa where aa.id = ? and aa.form_id = ?") .setParameter(1, id) .setParameter(2, form_id); BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) q.getSingleResult(); if ( bd != null) sonuc = (Byte) bd.byteValueExact(); return sonuc;` The problem is solved either way.

Comment: I still wonder if there is a way to get the result (sonuc) in Byte or Integer type in the first place directly by executing the native query (so that I won't have to bother converting BigDecimal to Byte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max(faz)
```

should be,

```
max(s.faz)
```

(an you are executing JPQL not a native SQL query)

Comment: james, your answer is correct and solves some of the problem, however I never got it to work wth EclipseLink without converting it to a native query. See my earlier comment above.